# Is it possible for users to sign-up for new accounts through Firebase Auth without installing your app?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-authentication, google-play

I have recently published an app that uses Firebase Auth. I see new accounts being created in the Firebase Console, but i don't see new installs on my Google Play Console.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At the time of this writing (August 2019), if `Firebase Auth` has sign-in methods enabled in the [Firebase console](https://console.firebase.google.com), then multiple accounts may be created through Web, Android, or iOS. There is no restriction preventing multiple accounts being created from a single App install.

A related question, is whether or not it is possible to keep `Auth` sign-ins enabled, and restrict account creation (sign-ups) for scenarios such as:

- Apps intended for internal/limited use only (but still available via app stores or public web page)
- Allow users to sign-up through an Android or iOS app, but prevent users from signing-up through a web app
- Prevent sign-up from the same user with different email addresses

See `firebase/firebaseui-web` feature request: [**Disable new user signups**](https://github.com/firebase/firebaseui-web/issues/99)